# Custom protocol handler, Windows

Tags: windows, registry, regedit

I wanted to try custom protocols on my machine, I added registry entries

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\customprotocol]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:customprotocol"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\customprotocol\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\customprotocol\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\customprotocol\shell\open\command]
@="\"echo %1 > C:\\logs\\alive.txt\""
```

But script doesn't seem to fire. Ever. Note that value `@="\"echo %1 > C:\\logs\\alive.txt\""` is the one I put there after I encountered a problem. Target value is something like `@="\"C:\\run_protocol.bat %1 \""`
For now I just want to create a file on my machine, when I get it working I'll run the script I want.
I have a prompt in the browser, however script never launches. I already restarted the machine.

Comment: `Echo` is not a standalone command, it is internal to `cmd.exe`, so perhaps you should consider using `cmd /c echo …` If you want more specific help, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62467106/edit) to properly explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Compo I wrote what I wanted to do and fixed example of target. My intention is to run .bat script.

Comment: Also, I tried your advice ```@="\"cmd /c C:\\run_protocol.bat\""``` fails to start.

Comment: That wasn't my advice, and what you've now tried doesn't use `echo` or the argument! Also can I clarify that your intention is to run a batch file with an unspecified argument, whenever you click on something you're keeping secret, in a web page? If so can I clarify that you've modified your browser, or server side code, and made changes to the security of your PC in order to be able to perform such a task?

Comment: Finally I want to have something Visual Studio Code does: when you do ```vscode:///path/to/file``` opens the file located on your PC in that location. I'm trying to set up somewhat similar system - when exception gets thrown in my app I want to have it be a link, which will open the problematic file in desired IDE. I want it passed to batch script first I get to play with it, maybe change format if needed, find it on disk or so.
I've already modified registry, server is putting out links already. I haven't modified browser though. I'm using Google Chrome, if that's relevant.